# Fastest way to find out a number with most divisors

Tags: algorithm, performance, time

Given a number `n` how fast can one find the smallest number with most factors and is less than n?
PS:other than the naive approach of finding number of divisors for all numbers upto `n`.

UPDATE : My observation:

```
int solve(int primes[],int s,int n)
{
    int i=0;
    while(s<n)
    {
        s*=primes[i];
        i++;
    }
    if(s>n)
        s/=primes[i-1];
    return s;
}
int main()
{
    int primes[] = {2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37};
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int s=1;
    while(s*2<n)//checking the possibility of existence of any prime such that s*p<n
    {
        s=solve(primes,s,n);
    }
    printf("%d\n",s);
}
```

The [output](https://ideone.com/sN7lN7) for this for `100000` is `60060`. Is this observation true? Because I don't have any concrete proof of this approach.
What I observed is that suppose take a prime array `{2,3,5,7,11}` and suppose that the given `n` is `100`. Then observe that keep multiplying distinct primes until that point that you get it `>100`. That is `2*3*5`.Repeat multiplying primes from the array from the first element again.That is `2*3*5*2`. This is the number required `60` with `12` factors.Now there is no prime that can be multiplied without exceeding `100`. Is this observation true? If its true then with primes upto `37` we can deal with `n<=10000000` easily.All the numbers below `100` with most factors are `60, 72, 84, 90` and `96`. We get the smallest of these numbers with this approach. All have `12` factors. No number below 100 has more than `12` factors.

Comment: Is querying oeis an option?

Comment: By most factors, do you mean most unique, prime factors (6 = 2, 3; 8 = 2) or number of prime factors (6 = 2,3; 8 = 2,2,2) or number of unique factors (6 = 1,2,3,6; 8 = 1,2,4,8) or something else?

Comment: @Eric number of unique factors (6 = 1,2,3,6; 8 = 1,2,4,8)

Comment: @Eric @NazarriBardiuk @mojtaba357 what I observed is that suppose take a prime array `{2,3,5,7,11}` and suppose that the given `n` is `100`. Then observe that keep multiplying distinct primes until that point that you get it `>100`. That is `2*3*5`.Repeat multiplying primes from the array from the first element again.That is `2*3*5*2`. This is the number required `60` with `12` factors.Now there is no prime that can be multiplied without exceeding `100`. Is this observation true? If its true then with primes upto `37` we can deal with `n<=10000000` easily.

Comment: All the numbers below `100` with most factors are  `60`, `72`, `84`, `90` and `96`. We get the smallest of these numbers with this approach. All have `12` factors. No number below `100` has more than `12` factors.

Comment: If you're interested in some reading. These numbers you are searching for are called Highly Composite. There is at least one paper written about a method of calculating them: http://wwwhomes.uni-bielefeld.de/achim/julianmanuscript3.pdf

Comment: Is preprocess for finding all primes < N too slow?

Comment: @shole Yes..at least for N ordering to 10^9...actually its not needed if my approach is proved correct...as you can see by using till `37`...we are able to deal with `n<=10000000`.....by using upto `41` or `43` we may solve until `n<=10000000000`

Comment: @yobro97 even using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Atkin  to achieve O(N)?

Comment: @shole...could you please convert this into code. Even if you have achieved this in `O(N)` time.....how are u planning to proceed for solving the question?

Comment: @yobro97 Indeed I think your observation is correct, I have an answer (I will undelete it after clarify stuff) which very similar to yours, basically I want to use the famous Hamming Number generating algorithm which is O(N). But instead of using {2,3,5}, I think we have to use all prime < the bound you set, which has to find all primes under your bound. After reading your comments, indeed this is what you have done.

Comment: @shole If you have gone through the comments, I have mentioned multiplying primes until it exceeds the number. Multiplication of all primes until `37` exceeds the `10000000`. So I think it is not needed to calculate all primes upto `10000000`, if you are trying to do similar to what I have done.....

Comment: @yobro97 I have undelete the answer, and my argument on why this method is correct based on the nature of hamming number generating algorithm...

Comment: `See comments for further description` is not what we do on [so]. Please [edit] your question and put the explanation there.

Comment: @xenteros...cool...I have added that in the question.....

Comment: @yobro97 Please tell me what's your final solution if you solved your problem (no matter use which method), I am interested in this problem as well :)

Comment: @shole I hope you know this property http://www.cut-the-knot.org/blue/NumberOfFactors.shtml . According to this, let `k=6`, the number of factors are `(1+1)*(1+1)=4`.Assume I multiplied it by a prime number already existing in its factors, for ex. `2`, then no. of factors are `(2+1)*(1+1)=6`. But assume I multiplied it by another prime (preferably the next one as we need smallest),say `5`, then no. of factors is `(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)=8`, which is greater. Thus I came to a conclusion that we have to go on multiplying distinct primes until not possible, and then look out for repeating...

Comment: @shole I hope you understood my logic. Till now I have not found any case where my logic fails. I am waiting for any concrete mathematical proof or anyone who can show my logic failing somewhere.....

Comment: @yobro97 yes I understand your logic, again, this is part of the nature and mindset behind Dijkstra's Hamming number generating algorithm,  thus this algorithm itself is a proof to your algorithm...

Comment: This is called "highly composite numbers". See: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2JM2oImb9Qg

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highly_composite_number

Answer (score 1):

I think this problem can be solved by algorithm similar to [Hamming Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_number), indeed your original concept is very similar to Hamming Number as well.

Hamming Number is a problem to generate number `x`, where `x = 2^i * 3*j * 5*k`, from **small to large** in `O(N)` where N is the number of hamming number to be generated.

Here, I think similar concept can be used but we have to **use the set of prime which is below your upper bound instead of {2,3,5}**, we just need to also count the maximum # of prime factors when generating the number, and output it after the number generated is larger than N.

---

For example, here is the list of hamming number(using {2,3,5} for demo purpose) < 100:

`1 2 3 4 5 6 8 9 10 12 15 16 18 20 24 25 27 30 32 36 40 45 48 50 54 60 64 72 75 80 81 90 96 100`

60 = 2^2 * 3^1 * 5^1, total factors = 3*2*2 = 12  or

96 = 2^5 * 3^1, total factors = 6*2 = 12

So there may be multiple answer but you should be able to capture them while generating hamming number.

---

One can show that it is logically correct because

1. The numbers are generated by prime numbers (prime factors)
2. The numbers are generated in order

Note that in your case, basically you are generating all positive numbers from 1 to your upper bound.

Here is a site with tons of example in different language implementing this algorithm to generate hamming numbers: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Hamming_numbers

Answer (score 0):

Adapting [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) it is doable in O(n^2) time.

- Start with an array of size `n` i.e `divisors`.
- For each number `k` less than `n` increment `divisors[k]` and all other indexes that are `k*i < n`
- Find index of the larger value in `divisors`

Comment: number k is prime?

Comment: number `k` is every number less than `n` i.e. `2 .. n`

Comment: This is equivalent to the naive approach the OP wanted to avoid.