# How do I find the number with the most divisors in an array?

Tags: c++, arrays

I have to input numbers into an array and at the end get the number that has the most divisors, or if there are more numbers with the same amount, print out the first one.

Example: 4 numbers, 6 12 48 108. 108 has the most divisors, so this one needs to show up. if there were numbers after 108 with the same amount of divisors, 108 would have still been the only one to show up.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n = 0, d, largestCnt = 0;
    int cntA=0, cntB=0;

    cout << "How many elements?\n";
    cin >> n;

    int* v = new int[n];

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        cin >> v[i];

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        for(d=2; d<v[i]/2; d++)
            if(v[i]%d==0)
            cntA++;
        for(d=2; d<v[i+1]/2; d++)
            if(v[i+1]%d==0)
            cntB++;
        if(cntA > largestCnt)
            largestCnt = cntA;
        if(cntB > largestCnt)
            largestCnt = cntB;
    }
    cout << largestCnt;

    return 0;
}
```

this is the most I've done the past 2 hours, and I can't get past it

EDIT:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n = 0, d;
    int mostDivisors=0, number_with_most_divisors=0;
    int currentDivisors = 0;

    cout << "How many elements?\n";
    cin >> n;

    int* v = new int[n];

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        cin >> v[i];

    number_with_most_divisors = v[0];
    
    for(d=2; d<=v[0]/2; d++){
        if(v[0]%d == 0)
            mostDivisors++;
    }
    for(int i=1; i<n; i++){
        for(d=2; d<=v[i]/2; d++)
            if(v[i]%d == 0)
                currentDivisors++;
                
        if(currentDivisors > mostDivisors){
            mostDivisors = currentDivisors;
            number_with_most_divisors = v[i];
        }
    }
    cout << number_with_most_divisors;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your problem? Does it not compile? If so, please copy and paste error message. Does it print incorrect output? If so, please provide inputs, expected and actual output.

Comment: One thing, `d<v[i+1]/2;` will go out of bound of `v` in the last iteration. You shouldn't need that loop at all. And you are not resetting `cntA` and `cntB` between loop iterations.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38596178/8344060

Comment: Have a look at: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-divisors-n-on13/

Comment: counting the divisors doesnt help me, i need to find a way for the program to do what i said in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the algorithm of what you have to do:

1. Count the number of divisors of the first element in array. Save this value in `mostDivisors`. Set `number_with_most_divisors` as the first element in the array.
2. Start from the second element in array (position 1) and for each element, count how many divisors it has, save it in `currentDivisors`. If `currentDivisors > mostDivisors` then set `mostDivisors` to be equal to `currentDivisors` and update `number_with_most_divisors` to be the current element in the array.
3. The result is `number_with_most_divisors` at the end of the loop.

**`UPDATE`**

You are forgetting to initialize `currentDivisors` for each element after the first loop:

```
for(int i=1; i<n; i++){
        currentDivisors = 0; // You forgot to put this line!
        for(d=2; d<=v[i]/2; d++)
            if(v[i]%d == 0)
                currentDivisors++;
                
        if(currentDivisors > mostDivisors){
            mostDivisors = currentDivisors;
            number_with_most_divisors = v[i];
        }
```

Comment: i am pretty stupid so i did kinda like what you told me to but it doesnt work so i am going to update my question with the new program and maybe you can take a look at it

Comment: @MickeyMoise Will update here based on your code

Answer (score 0):

```
// function to count the divisors 
int countDivisors(int n) 
{ 
    int cnt = 0; 
    for (int i = 1; i <= sqrt(n); i++) { 
        if (n % i == 0) { 
            // If divisors are equal, 
            // count only one 
            if (n / i == i) 
                cnt++; 
  
            else // Otherwise count both 
                cnt = cnt + 2; 
        } 
    } 
    return cnt; 
}
```

You can loop to enter the numbers into an array

Comment: i need to use only 1 function, that's 1 of my issues

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int n = 0, max_divs = 0, count = 0, max_divs_index = 0;
    std::cin >> n;
    int *v = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) std::cin >> v[i];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        count = 0; // resetting count to 0 in each iteration
        for (int j = 2; j < v[i]/2; ++j)
            if (v[i] % j == 0) count++; // checking if the number is divisible by numbers between 1 and number itself/2 (1 and num/2 exclusive)
        if (count > max_divs) { // checking if current count is greater than the maximum divisors
            max_divs = count; // updating maximum divisors
            max_divs_index = i; // updating the index of array element with maximum divisors
        }
    }
    std::cout << v[max_divs_index];
    delete[] v;
    return 0;
}
```